# What is wrong in this code to throw an ObjectDisposedException?

Tags: c#, semaphore

It's a little hard for me to understand the actual behavior in this scenario. What is actually happening to not execute the task when expected but later when SemaphoreSlim has been disposed? It throws the following exception-
`System.ObjectDisposedException {"The semaphore has been disposed."}`

I have a class library like -

```
public class ParallelProcessor
{
    private Action[] actions;
    private int maxConcurrency;

    public ParallelProcessor(Action[] actionList, int maxConcurrency)
    {
        this.actions = actionList;
        this.maxConcurrency = maxConcurrency;
    }

    public void RunAllActions()
    {
        if (Utility.IsNullOrEmpty<Action>(actions))
            throw new Exception("No Action Found!");

        using (SemaphoreSlim concurrencySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrency))
        {
            foreach (Action action in actions)
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    concurrencySemaphore.Wait();
                    try
                    {
                        action();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        concurrencySemaphore.Release();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm using it like-

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int maxConcurrency = 3;
        Action[] actions = new Action[] { () => Console.WriteLine(1), () => Console.WriteLine(2), () => Console.WriteLine(3) }; //Array.Empty<Action>();

        ParallelProcessor processor = new ParallelProcessor(actions, maxConcurrency);

        processor.RunAllActions();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Could anybody please shed some light on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is your `using` statement. This is how things are happening:

- Create the semaphore
- Start tasks running in the background
- Dispose of the semaphore
- Tasks try to use the semaphore... but can't, because it's disposed

Options:

- Just remove the `using` statement (so you don't dispose of the semaphore, but that's unlikely to be a problem unless you're using this *really* heavily)
- Change your method to block (inside the `using` statement) until all the tasks have completed, e.g. by using `Parallel.ForEach` instead of calling `Task.Factory.StartNew` directly
- Change your code to dispose of the semaphore in a task which will only execute after all the other tasks have completed

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining the order of execution. It's my bad :( I didn't notice the blunders of using both 'using' & 'Task'. Once again thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your semaphore is disposed at the end of the `using` block, but used by the still running Task created inside it.
I would recommend moving the semaphore up to the class level:

```
public class ParallelProcessor
{
    private Action[] actions;
    private SemaphoreSlim concurrencySemaphore;

    public ParallelProcessor(Action[] actionList, int maxConcurrency)
    {
        this.actions = actionList;
        concurrencySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrency);
    }

    public void RunAllActions()
    {
        if (Utility.IsNullOrEmpty<Action>(actions))
            throw new Exception("No Action Found!");

        foreach (Action action in actions)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    concurrencySemaphore.Wait();
                    try
                    {
                        action();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        concurrencySemaphore.Release();
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

or an alternative approach, where `RunAllActions` will block until all are done:

```
public class ParallelProcessor
{
    private Action[] actions;
    private int maxConcurrency;

    public ParallelProcessor(Action[] actionList, int maxConcurrency)
    {
        this.actions = actionList;
        this.maxConcurrency = maxConcurrency;
    }

    public void RunAllActions()
    {
        if (Utility.IsNullOrEmpty<Action>(actions))
            throw new Exception("No Action Found!");

        using (var concurrencySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrency))
        {
            Task.WaitAll(actions.Select(a => Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    concurrencySemaphore.Wait();
                    try { a(); }
                    finally { concurrencySemaphore.Release(); }
                })).ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is dispose the concurrencySemaphore which is already in the using statement.

The main use of **Using** is, it will automatically add try and finally and in finally it will dispose the object that is under **using**.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6564/Understanding-the-using-statement-in-C

The solution for your case is either remove the using or remove the finally statement